# sed command in single quotes works but it doesn't using double quotes

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, given this `test.file` content:

```
Hello \there
```

why does this (from the command line):

```
sed 's#\\there#where#' test.file
```

work, but this:

```
sed "s#\\there#where#" test.file
```

does not? Is it a matter of configuration?

The former succesfully replaces the pattern, while the latter doesn't seem to find any match.
I need to use a variable within the replacement text in a script, so I (guess I) need double quotes around the sed command.

Comment: There is no reason for this that I can see. You will need to expand your question to show real file data and search patterns.

Comment: @AFH You're both right, it seems it is a matter of backslashes in the input file -- see my edit.

Comment: Yes, single- and double-quotes handle back-slashes differently.

Comment: Plus, `sed` does its own back-slash interpretation.

Comment: "need double quotes around the `sed` command" -- Your shell should concatenate quoted strings. Consider this trick: `sed 's#\\there#'"$foo"'#' test.file`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash` and other shells, the back-slash character is handled differently within single- or double-quotes.

When you type `sed 's#\\there#where#' test.file`, what `sed` sees in its run string is `s#\\there#where# test.file`, because single quotes prevent all special character and escape-sequence interpretation: even `\'` is disallowed.

When you type `sed "s#\\there#where#" test.file`, what `sed` sees in its run string is `s#\there#where# test.file`, because double-quotes allow some escape sequences, and the shell has interpreted the first back-slash as escaping the second.

The further complication is that `sed` also allows escape sequence interpretation, similar to that in double-quoting, so in the first case (single-quoted) the search string becomes `\there`, as you want; whereas in the second case (double-quoted) the search string's first character becomes a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, followed by `here`.

The following extract from the `bash` manual defines these actions:-

> ```
>    There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single quotes, and double quotes.
>
>    A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character.  It preserves the literal value of the next character that
>    follows, with the exception of <newline>.  If a \<newline> pair appears,  and  the  backslash  is  not  itself
>    quoted,  the  \<newline>  is  treated as a line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and
>    effectively ignored).
>
>    Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.  A sin‐
>    gle quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
>    Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with
>    the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ and ` retain their spe‐
>    cial meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the
>    following characters: $, `, ", \, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by  preced‐
>    ing  it  with  a  backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an !  appearing in double
>    quotes is escaped using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.
>
>    The special parameters * and @ have special meaning when in double quotes (see PARAMETERS below).
>
>    Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped charac‐
>    ters  replaced  as  specified  by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as
>    follows:
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex
>                  digits)
>           \UHHHHHHHH
>                  the  Unicode  (ISO/IEC  10646)  character  whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to
>                  eight hex digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
>
>    The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.
>
>    A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be translated  according
>    to  the  current  locale.   If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string is
>    translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.
> ```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - You are quite correct. I had made a couple of references to the shell interpretation of `Tab`, which I found untrue when I checked, but I mistakenly deleted only one of them. Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: Way to go. +1 then.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have mentioned that I'm trying to match the text `127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

Comment: @watery - If you use single-quotes, you will have no problems with this string; if you use double-quotes, you need to double the back-slashes, just as in the sample string in your question needs to be `sed "s#\\\\there#where#" test.file` with double-quotes. I have had instances where I've needed to use eight back-slashes for each one in the string I am trying to define!

Comment: @watery - Note that the `|` will need to be escaped to specify an alternative match string if you are using basic regular expressions (no `-r` in the `sed` run string); otherwise, it will be treated as a literal. The reverse is true with `-r` (extended REs): `|` specifies alternative strings, while `\|` matches a literal `|`.

Comment: Yep, the final working pattern has been `127\\\\\.\\\\d\\+\\\\\.\\\\d\\+\\\\\.\\\\d\\+\\|::1\\|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` and yes I'm using `-r`